# Object not found! ERROR 404

Tags: php, href

When I click on a div I get directed to some page and there occurs the **ERROR 404_**

**dummy1_memo.php:**

```
<div>
    <a href="dummy2_memo.php?id=<?php echo $row['memo_id']; ?>">
        <h3><?php echo $for; ?></h3><p>
        <?php echo $ation; ?><br><?php echo $subj; ?><br><?php echo $date; ?><br><?php echo $affected_rows; ?>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you *have* a `dummy2_memo.php` in the same directory from where you access dummy1_memo?

Comment: @LSerni yes....

Comment: So what you should do is verify (using Firebug, Chrome developer tools or whatever) what you're asking the server, and checking its error log (in Apache that would be /var/log/apache2/error_log or something) to see what was received, and what happened.

Comment: i already tried this in my upload file before. it works perfectly fine but not this time :( kinda frustrating

Comment: @LSerni i had no idea what you're saying... sorry but how should i do that?

Comment: Hm. I'm beginning to fear that you approached this from the wrong side. You need to be familiar with your development environment - the server you're using, the tools at your disposal - *before* starting with the code. Otherwise you will be repeatedly stumped at every difficulty. Also, this is key information that you should supply in your questions (the path I quoted above is for Linux systems, but maybe you're on a Mac or use Windows. You didn't say, I assumed Linux as that's what I'm used to). For the error log, try googling for "location of *your_server*'s error_log on *your_OS*".

Comment: i really am a beginner so i am not that familiar. but i already checked the error_log and it says something like "The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters" ..